# Add HTTP Header to Wicket Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest, wicket

I need to add a HTTP header to all Ajax (XHR) Requests of Wicket. I've tried the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-My-Header', 'value');
    }
});
```

and

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-My-Header', 'value');
});
```

It doesn't work.

What did I wrong?

How can I solve this?

**SOLUTION**

Wicket uses it's own stuff to register global listeners.

```
Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/beforeSend', function(jqEvent, attributes, jqXHR, errorThrown, textStatus) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-My-Header', 'value');
});
```

Comment: Wicket itself uses beforeSend() to set the content type: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/bcd55813b3afbccb5675096930aee6281c5cba3a/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery.js#L682. It uses local settings though. But your approach should work. Did you try to debug it? Is the function called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why your attempts failed, but wicket provides support for such requirements with AJAX global listeners. Search for paragraph 'Global listener' in this chapter:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/ajax.html#ajax_6

Comment: It's because Wicket uses it's own stuff to register global listeners, see my solution above. Thanks for the input !! :)